# How to convert a String with new lines into HTML list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a string with multiple lines. Example:

```
string = "line1\nline2\nline3"
```

I need to print it out on my page in HTML unordered list.

Comment: explode it to an array and then do a loop.

Comment: See [`String#each_line`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-each_line)

Comment: Use split in controller and array renderer in view

Answer (score 2):

You can use either String#each_line a suggested by @LeonidLukin or String#split + Array#join as suggested by @jcubic. I prefer the following to jcubic's solution because his code creates an empty line item at the end:

```
<ul>
  <% string.each_line do |line| %>
    <li><%= line.chomp %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby I will do this:

```
"<ul><li>" + ("line1\nline2\nline3".split("\n").join("</li><li>")) + "</li></ul>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!
I did it this way:

```
<ul>
<%
   string = "line1\nline2\nline3"
   lines = string.split("\n")
   lines.each do |line|
%>
  <li><%= line %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

But now I'd like to try using `String.html#method-i-each_lin`

Answer (score 0):

Same as the answer with split+join, Only that you can use gsub:

```
"<ul><li>"+"line1\nline2\nline3".gsub("\n", "</li><li>")+"</li></ul>"
```